# Unable to Retrieve data from PHP class

Tags: php

In the following code I am getting error: `Undefined variable: base_url on line 27` and `Cannot access empty property on line 27`.

I need to echo  the parameter `http://google.com` passed in get_url() from render().

```
<?php

$smart_url = new smart();

$smart_url -> get_url('http://google.com');

echo  $smart_url -> render();


 /**
 * Smart URL
 */

class smart {

private $base_url;

/**
 * 
 * @param string $url
 */
public function get_url($url) {
        $this -> $base_url = $url;

}


/**
 * @return string $base_url
 */
public function render() {
    return $this -> $base_url;


}

}


?>
```

Comment: This is a common PHP newbies mistake. Don't vote down on the question. And just btw as much is it asked as much easier it will be for newcomers to find their mistake. I asked a similar question myself an year ago. :D

Answer (score 1):

It's just a syntax error. You access your parameters this way:

```
 $this->base_url;
```

Without the `$`before the parameters' name

Answer (score 1):

Syntactically incorrect...
 $this -> $base_url = $url;

Should be

```
$this->base_url = $url;
```

Answer (score 1):

`$this -> $base_url` is wrong; no $ ,`$this->base_url`

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer:**

Use: `$this->base_url`

**Long answer:**

When you are accessing properties you don't need the dollar sign. Access them simply as that:

```
$this->base_url
```

The second one would access a class property with the name $base_url (the content of the variable).

This is a common mistake. Use the dollar sign only for declaring variables in this context:

```
protected $base_url;
```